# Complexity of determining whether a LP or MIP is infeasible

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, computational-complexity

What is the best complexity for the worst case scenario and the algorithm associated with it to determine if a linear programming (LP) is infeasible ? Further, what if we consider a mixed integer programming (MIP) ? Note that I only would like to know whether the problem is infeasible.

So far, I believe the worst case scenario would be a NP-Hard problem modeled as either a LP or MIP and, determining whether our model is infeasible, would be NP-Hard as well, i. e. complexity of O(2<sup>n</sup>) where `n` is the number of variables in our model.

Comment: LP is in P, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmarkar%27s_algorithm) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method). IP feasibility is NP complete, seh [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems). I am not sure about MIP, but I guess, we could ask an oracle for the solution to the integer variables, fix them and solve the remaining LP in polynomial time, so MIP-feasibility should also be in NP and thus NP complete as IP is already NP complete.

Comment: To clarify my last comment: Only IP-feasibility is NP-complete. IP-optimality is (to the best of our knowledge) harder as one has to show that there is no better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! You should post this as an answer.